# Google JS Coding Conventions - "The var keyword must not be used"

Tags: javascript, convention

I am having troubles understanding [this paragraph](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-use-const-and-let):

> Declare all local variables with either `const` or `let`.
>   Use const by default, unless a variable needs to be reassigned.
>   The `var` keyword must not be used

Could someone please explain what this means? Why shouldn't I use the 'var' keyword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those conventions are assuming ES2015 and above, which have `let` and `const`, which can be used to replace `var`. They're saying don't use `var` anymore, because the `let` and `const` semantics are more useful (according to those conventions *[and my own personal opinion, not that that matters]*).

So for example, they're saying don't do this:

```
function foo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // Do something with i
    }
}
```

instead, either do this:

```
function foo() {
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // Do something with i
    }
}
```

or this (but note that performance will be slightly slower with this last version, not that it usually matters<sup>1</sup>):

```
function foo() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // Do something with i
    }
}
```

Similarly, if you're using a variable whose value will never change, use `const`:

```
function getTomorrow() {
    const date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    return date;
}
```

We can use `const` there because the value of `date` never changes (just the state of the object it refers to).

If you're anything like me, when you put these into practice (I don't follow those conventions, but I do follow this specific example of using `let` and `const`), if you're using other good practices (like keeping functions small, etc.), you'll be surprised at just how often you use `const` rather than `let` because you end up with a lot of "variables" whose values you never want to change.

---

<sup>1</sup> You may be wondering why there's a performance difference between

```
function foo() {
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // Do something with i
    }
}
```

and

```
function foo() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // Do something with i
    }
}
```

The reason is that in the second one, a **new** `i` variable is created for every loop iteration. We can see that if we create a closure inside the loop:

```js
function foo1() {
    console.log("let outside the loop:");
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(i);
        }, 0);
    }
}
function foo2() {
    console.log("let inside the loop:");
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(i);
        }, 0);
    }
}

foo1();
setTimeout(foo2, 50);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Again, the performance difference almost never matters (and will get smaller as engines get better at optimizing it out when they can), and lots of times you want the behavior of the second form (which is why it's defined that way). But it's there.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why performance differs with putting `let` inside `for` bracers?

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny: Done.

Comment: but I thought const is something into which you hardcode a value, not define the value at runtime

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in your runnable example, the first loop outputs `5,5,5,5,5` instead of `0,1,2,3,4`, removing the `setTimeout()` inside the for loop fixes this. but what could be the cause of this?

Comment: @KevinKloet: That's what the example is pointing out: When the `let` is *inside* the `for` construct, a separate `i` is created for each loop iteration, specifically so that closures get a separate `i` to close over and we get the `0,1,2,3,4` behavior. Declaring `i` *outside* the loop means there's only one `i` for the entire thing, and they close over it, and thus see `5` when they run.

Comment: Yay, *two* new ways to get confused by the way variables are incremented in loops!

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer: No, `const` is useful for much more than that. You can use it **any** time the "variable" you're declaring won't change throughout its use -- which turns out to be really often, such as my `date` example above. I have to admit I didn't see it coming, but after I'd been writing ES2015+ code for a couple of weeks, I suddenly realized "Hey, these never change, I could..." And I'm not the only one, preferring `const` to `let` is showing up in lots of conventions and blogs.

Comment: @ppajer yeah, as if the non-existant rules of coding in javascript werent enough

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer: I'm not following you there. JavaScript has just as many, and just as few, "rules of coding" as any other language.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean that in javascript you don't have some strict rules like in the compiled languages

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer: Er, yes, you do. And JavaScript *is* compiled, these days; it's just compiled at the last minute. If you want, you can use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) (or any of several others) to give you proactive notification of errors like a compilation step on your machine would.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder To be honest I really like `const` both in its uses and semantics. I just seem to have some sort of instinctive aversion to the way `let` looks in my code, and miss my good old `var`s unless it is in the form of `let it_be;` :D

Comment: @ppajer: :-D I'm fine with `let a = 42;` It's `let a;` on its own that looks odd to me, like an incomplete...